# Как настроить geoip в проекте laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Установил я geoip по этой странице:

```
http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/
```

У меня 2 страницы (русс и англ языки). Я так понимаю, что в файле public/index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

нужно прописать функцию getClientIP() ,

```
получить ip пользователя -> 
сравнить его с базой     ->
вытянуть из массива данные по 'country' ->
сравнить 'country'         ->
if('country' == 'USA') {
    return view('welcome-eng');
} else {
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Верны ли мои суждения? и КАК реализовать код остальных пунктов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще один вариант решения, НЕиспользуя модуль:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$country = geoip_country_name_by_name($ip);
echo 'The current user is located in: ' . $country;
```

По этой ссылке функции, с помощью которых можно узнать нужную информацию по ip-адресу:

```
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://api.2ip.ua/geo.json?ip=";
// делаем запрос к API
$data = file_get_contents($url);

// если получили данные
if($data){
// декодируем полученные данные
$dataDecode = json_decode($data);

// выводим данные
echo "Страна: " . $dataDecode->country . "<br/>";
echo "Код страны: " . $dataDecode->country_code . "<br/>";
echo "Город: " . $dataDecode->city . "<br/>";
echo "Область: " . $dataDecode->region . "<br/>";
echo "Широта: " . $dataDecode->latitude . "<br/>";
echo "Долгота: " . $dataDecode->longitude . "<br/>";
echo "Часовой пояс: " . $dataDecode->time_zone . "<br/>";

}else{
echo "Сервер не доступен!";
}
```